# how to fix this find bugs Potential Path Traversal in new File(filePath)

Tags: java, security, findbugs

```
public void createFile(String filePath) {
  File file = new File(filePath);
}

change to ====>

public void createFile(String filePath) {
  File file = new File(FilenameUtils.getFullPath(pathName), 
                       FilenameUtils.getName(pathName));
}
```

but it still has bugs Potential Path Traversal, how to fix this find bugs? thank you.

with hard code is ok, but it's not fit my requirement.

```
public void createFile(String filePath) {
  File file = new File("resource/image/", 
                       FilenameUtils.getName(pathName));
}
```

Comment: Is it a `Dynamic Web Project`? Where is your image directory located?

Comment: it's only an example, my meaning is if use hardcode path + FilenameUtils.getName(pathName)), it will not report this bugs. however use FilenameUtils.getFullPath(pathName) + FilenameUtils.getName(pathName)) it will report this bugs. I want to know how to fix this bugs without hardcode? thanks.

Comment: it's java project, this bugs report for new File(pathName) function variable.

Comment: If you are using servlets, try to use `getServletContext().getRealPath("/image")`

Comment: hi, Chinamay, it's not a web project, the filePath is not a sure value.

Comment: I doubt that it can't be fixed. You need to "normalize" the input to fix this. That means either hard coding the full path, configuring it in the project or making it persistent into the database.

Comment: Hi danny, I would say instead of using this complicated structure, you can simply use JFileChooser. When the file dialog is open, you can create the type of file you want by right click->New->file type. You can then modify its extension as per your need. Also it will allow you to traverse the path also. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to fix it is to not use variable input to access files on the server. One of the suggestions from here https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/73.html

> When the set of filenames is limited or known, create a mapping from a
>   set of fixed input values (such as numeric IDs) to the actual
>   filenames, and reject all other inputs. For example, ID 1 could map to
>   "inbox.txt" and ID 2 could map to "profile.txt". Features such as the
>   ESAPI AccessReferenceMap provide this capability.

Your code is still detected by `SonarQube` as non-valid because even if you use `FilenameUtils.getName()`, your code still uses user-provided variables as parts of the file path.